# Why does the content only render after onChange?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rc-slider

I'm using [rc-slider](http://react-component.github.io/slider/) to take a bunch of values from an array and render them in my component.

```
const array = ["Hey", "Ho", "Me", "Too", "See"]
class App extends Component {
  state = { sliderValues: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] };

  handleChange = sliderValues => {
    this.setState({ sliderValues }, () => console.log(array[this.state.sliderValues]));
  };

  render() {
    const renderContent = array.map((value, index) => {
      console.log(value, 'value')
      console.log(index, 'index')
      if (index === this.state.sliderValues) {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>{value}</h1>
          </div>
        )
      }
    })
    return (
      <div>
        {renderContent}
        <Slider onChange={this.handleChange} min={0} max={4} defaultValue={this.state.sliderValues} marks={{ 0: 250, 1: 500, 2: 750, 3: 1000, 4: 1500 }} step={null} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I only want to show one item from the array at once. Everything works correctly besides on initial render. You'll notice that the component only renders itself once you've interacted with the `<Slider />.`.

Why is this?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6z0p7x2l3w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import React, {Component} from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import Slider from 'rc-slider'
    import "./styles.css";

    const array = ["Hey", "Ho", "Me", "Too", "See"]
    class App extends Component {
      // you need to provide an initial value to be rendered at the first time
      state = { sliderValues: 0 };

      handleChange = sliderValues => {
        this.setState({ sliderValues }, () => console.log(array[this.state.sliderValues]));
      };

      render() {
        const renderContent = array.map((value, index) => {
          console.log(value, 'value')
          console.log(index, 'index')
          if (index === this.state.sliderValues) {
            return (
              <div key={value}>
                <h1>{value}</h1>
              </div>
            )
          }
        })
        return (
          <div>
            {renderContent}
            <Slider onChange={this.handleChange} min={0} max={4} defaultValue={this.state.sliderValues} marks={{ 0: 250, 1: 500, 2: 750, 3: 1000, 4: 1500 }} step={null} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Ah, silly me. Thank you, will accept as answer in 3 minutes when it allows me. Cheers!

Comment: have a nice coding :D